# Transfer Access 2010 result table after existing content in Excel file

Tags: vba, excel, request, export

I need to come up with an updated VBA script that will transfer the result from an Access 2010 request into an existing Excel file, after the current content.

Here is the previous script, that worked with Access 97.

```
Private Sub CmdTransfert_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdTransfert_Click

    Dim Requete As QueryTable

    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim Classeur As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Cellule As Excel.Range
    Dim Plage As Excel.Range
    ' Bills that needs to be transfered
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Liste_factures_numero"

    ' Select answers
    SendKeys "^a", True
    ' Copy
    SendKeys "^c", True


    ' Opening Excel
    Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = True
    'Only XL 97 supports UserControl Property
    On Error Resume Next
    appXL.UserControl = True

    Set Classeur = appXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\copiedetravailvlvaccdb\reglements.xlsx")

    Set Cellule = Classeur.Worksheets(1).Cells(Classeur.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    Cellule.Select

    ' Paste
    SendKeys "^v", True
    ' Cellule.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Deleting titles
    Cellule.EntireRow.Delete

    'Fixing date format
    Set Plage = Selection
    For Each Cellule In Plage
        If Cellule.Column = 2 Then
            If Cellule.Value <> "" Then
                Cellule.Value = CDate(Cellule.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Mise au format normal
    Range("A3:D3").Copy
    Plage.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Closing request
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Liste_factures_numero", acSaveNo

Exit_CmdTransfert_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_CmdTransfert_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdTransfert_Click

End Sub
```

I have tried adding Sleep commands around the Sendkeys instruction, it did not worked. The result was not selected, thus not copied nor pasted.

As last resort I tried creating a new script using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, but I can't figure how to add the new content after the existing one.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "Liste_factures_numero", "C:\Users\me\Desktop\copiedetravailvlvaccdb\reglements.xlsx", True
```

However as expected it overwrite the content.
This is my first time with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Liste_factures_numero"

' Select answers
SendKeys "^a", True
' Copy
SendKeys "^c", True
```

To this:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Liste_factures_numero"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
```

And this:

```
' Paste
SendKeys "^v", True
```

To this:

```
Cellule.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Also, I must add that it's another way to achieve this copy-pasting from Access to Excel via macros:

1. Make connection to Access file;
2. Get data from query into recordset;
3. Paste data on excel sheet;
4. Use formatting on pasted cells (font, size etc).

Comment: @Relkco My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, changing worksheets/column A as necessary:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "Liste_factures_numero" _
    , ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(35) & "Sheet1", True, r.Address
```